# Loop in Django Model

Tags: django, list, for-loop, django-models, ipv4

I have a IP Block calculator web application that will print a range of IP addresses based on slashes. However it only saves the last record in the range into the text field. I want to be able to save it all to the text field.

I am using python-ipy with my code. Look at the last for loop **"rangeip"**,

Here is my code:

```
#ip block and range save function 

def save(obj, *args, **kwargs):

        subnet = unicode(obj.subnet)

        first = IP(obj.ip_start + subnet).net()
        broadcast = IP(obj.ip_start + subnet).broadcast()

        print first
        print broadcast

        obj.broadcast_ip = broadcast

        ip_block = IP(obj.ip_start + subnet)
        ip_block.WantPrefixLen = 3


        ip = IP(obj.ip_start + subnet)

        for gateway in ip[1]:
            obj.gateway_ip = gateway
            print gateway

        #rangeip for loop

        for rangeip in ip:
            obj.ip_range = rangeip
            print rangeip

        super(IP_block, obj).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is what I would like, to be able to save the list into a text field, it only saves the last ip: 192.168.1.31

Example I would like:

192.168.1.1
192.168.1.0
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
192.168.1.6
192.168.1.7
192.168.1.8
192.168.1.9
192.168.1.10
192.168.1.11
192.168.1.12
192.168.1.13
192.168.1.14
192.168.1.15
192.168.1.16
192.168.1.17
192.168.1.18
192.168.1.19
192.168.1.20
192.168.1.21
192.168.1.22
192.168.1.23
192.168.1.24
192.168.1.25
192.168.1.26
192.168.1.27
192.168.1.28
192.168.1.29
192.168.1.30
192.168.1.31

Any help is greatly appreciate it.

Comment: how is `ip_range` defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.ip_range = rangeip` is an assignment. You are replacing the content of `obj.ip_range` with the new `rangeip`.

What you need to do is:

```
obj.ip_range += "%s"%rangeip
```

Comment: I have one more question, is it possible to add the ip list to a manytomanyfield?

Comment: Yes you can but y do you want to store so much redundant data?

Comment: I guess what I want is something that saves each ip to it's own field. Textfield works, but has no relationship.

Comment: You can save the start ip and subnet mask in a class and have a foreign key reference to it.

Comment: Another way - not so elegant is to save the whole data as a pickle field

Comment: I came up with another way. I want to convert the list into choices, I got something like this:                                                                                (0, 192.168.1.2)
(1, 192.168.1.3)
...
I'm just trying to pass the choice to another model, but having a hard time.

Comment: what problems are you facing?

Comment: I'm just having problems trying to figure out how to set it up. I just know how to output the list, but don't know how to add it to another model. Since it's not going into a physical field, it's just needs to go into another class and have IP_CHOICE = (), then need to go into, ip_list = models.CharField(choices=IP_CHOICE,). It will be related through the Start of IP and Subnet. I will make another post of my code.